# How read stream web cam in node.js for mac os?

Tags: macos, node.js, webcam

I seen analog lib "camelot" and "imagesnap" in npm repositories.
"camelot" - work only in linux os (because it uses /dev/videoX).
"imagesnap" - support only create jpg and not support created stream. Same it lib is binary.
What may be a simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

worked with lib https://github.com/wearefractal/camera, 
for mac os need install opencv, i'm use brew install opencv. 
it's really work!!

Comment: if brew show alert "Error: No available formula for opencv", type in console > brew tap homebrew/science

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got everything working yet, but connecting to GStreamer over TCP from Node looks promising:

http://delog.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/stream-live-webm-video-to-browser-using-node-js-and-gstreamer/

The tutorial is about Linux, but most things should have an OSX equivalent. To get started:

1. Install XQuartz: https://xquartz.macosforge.org
2. `brew install gstreamer`
3. `brew install gst-plugins-good`
4. `brew install gst-plugins-bad`

If everything installed properly, this command should give you a test video source:

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! osxvideosink`

I'm now trying to figure out how to get the webcam. I think the built-in webcam is locked down, but hopefully an external one might work.

I'm interested to hear if you make any progress!

Comment: I have only built-in webcam, i tested this method and did not achieve a good result. Thank you for answer. I will write if I'll get the result. The truth is out there!

Comment: "gst-launch-1.0 wrappercamerabinsrc mode=2 ! video/x-raw ! osxvideosink" this code get access to built-in webcam, i seen green indicator, but  don't video